# Java RMI server probleme

Tags: java, eclipse, client, rmi

i'm doing this tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkw275ptI3E
it's a java rmi tutorial (client, server)
but he try this on Local and it dosen't work on my Computer

When i try to activate my server in local i got this message :

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simple.rmi.server.MyServer_Stub
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at simple.rmi.server.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:33)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simple.rmi.server.MyServer_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:390)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simple.rmi.server.MyServer_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1185)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(LoaderHandler.java:1198)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:433)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:164)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:201)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1589)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    ... 12 more
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Have u exchanged the stub and skeleton?

Comment: what do you mean ?

click on RMI --> available stubs generation ?

Answer (score 0):

Some incompatible changes have been made in recent JDK versions that cause old RMI tutorials not to work. In particular, JDK 7u21 now requires you to set the codebase property on the client and the registry as well as on the server. The screencast only shows the setting on the server.

The screencast (or perhaps the Eclipse plugin) is also out of date in that it shows the generation of stubs. It's not necessary to use any tool such as `rmic` or an Eclipse plugin to generate stubs, since stubs have been generated automatically by RMI since Java SE 5 (which was released in 2002).